# NetBeans not support user icon in JOtionPane

Tags: java, image, netbeans, dialog, joptionpane

I tried a lot of code to show image in `JOptionPane` but it just displays the message without the image. No error  in my code.

What is the problem?

I use it with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.

What ever I do, no image is displayed in the `JOptionPane`.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("ok.png");
    String ttl = "example";
    String msg = "are you sure?";
    int ans = showConfirmDialog(null, msg, ttl, YES_NO_OPTION, 0, icon);
}
0, icon );
}
}
```

Comment: Neither I can understand the language of the problem nor the code. Please format the code.

Comment: There's lots of reasons you might be having problems.  `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the specified `String` is a "file" relative to the location from which the program is been run.  You could use `ImageIO.read` instead, it will throw a `IOException` if the image can't be read for some reason. See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: You can also use `System.out.println(new File("ok.png").exists())` to test if the file can be read from the current context